# Filter between date in sum by group in sql from two different tables data

Tags: sql, postgresql, vb.net

How are you, I have two tables one tables is PRODUCT and other tables is STOCK_sales, i use sum and group by,
But my problem is i can't not filter between dates.

in this link is my SQL database CODE and all structure how can i do this.
myquery

```
SELECT 
    Product.ProductID,buyprice,sellprice, SUM(sellqty) as Total 
FROM product,Stock_sales 
WHERE Product.ProductID=Stock_sales.ProductID 
GROUP BY Product.ProductID,buyprice,sellprice 
ORDER BY Product.ProductID
```

THANK YOU.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f2b78aab10cf770bc918206da6aaeecd

Answer (score 2):

You can use a where clause to filter the dates and other columns.

your FROM clause sould be wriiten by JOINS, your style is outdated for years

> ```
> SELECT Product.ProductID,buyprice,sellprice,
> SUM(sellqty) as Total
> FROM product INNER JOIN Stock_sales ON Product.ProductID=Stock_sales.ProductID
> WHERE data BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-04'
> GROUP BY Product.ProductID,buyprice,sellprice
> ORDER BY Product.ProductID
> ```
>
> ```
> productid | buyprice | sellprice | total
> --------: | -------: | --------: | ----:
>         1 |       10 |        20 |    20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=67a076a61fd2c7d542e7c7d27c924489)*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer by nbk.
However, if you want to continue with the WHERE clause specifying the key IDs instead of using a JOIN then you just need to extend that using AND:

```
WHERE Product.ProductID=Stock_sales.ProductID 
AND stock_sales.data = '2022-01-03'
```

or

```
WHERE Product.ProductID=Stock_sales.ProductID 
AND stock_sales.data BETWEEN '2022-01-03' AND '2022-01-17'
```

Comment: no coma separated tables, are3 very old fashions and are since 20 years not used anymore. Please don't encourage such code

Comment: @nbk I'm not encouraging old style syntax, just expanding on your correct answer for clarity. This syntax is still valid and required in legacy systems so providing an awareness is valid. With 30 years industry experience, I am quite aware of these things.

Comment: NB. The syntax is also still supported by Oracle, Sybase and Informix.